# Bold and italic in subsection

Tags: fonts, bold, italic

In the following documentclass

```
\documentclass[prb,twocolumn,showpacs]{revtex4}
```

how to have italic and bold in a subsection title?
The italic command removes the boldness when inside a subsection, so I tried the following :

```
\subsection{Short-range {\bf {\it vs}} long-range scattering}
```

It does not work.
Any idea how to solve this?
Maybe the documentclass has nothing to do with it, I  did not check it.

Comment: For the record, the [Documentation on Obsolete commands and packages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/) warns against continuing to use "\it" and "\bf".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the documentclass, but with font selection. `\it` selects non-bold italics, and `\bf` selects non-italic bold. You should use

```
\textbf{\textit{vs}}
```

instead. See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/1235).

Comment: +1 for the link to Caramdir's answer. I've deleted my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing `\textit{\textbf{vs}}` instead. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\secit{vs}` would solve the problem. This is how I worked it out for my subsection when I needed both bold and italic.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: How is `\secit` defined? `revtex4` does not include it.